# performance difference between createQuery and createNativeQuery JPA

Tags: jpa

I have a fairly large query and it is taking a long time to return data to me,  is worth it passing it to a createNativeQuery and not using JPA statements?. Excume for my bad english

Comment: jpql is translated to sql, you can simply print the sql created to compare

Comment: what is your query?